# ModuleFederationPlugin documentation

Tags: webpack, webpack-module-federation

Does someone know where I can find documentation on webpack's [ModuleFederationPlugin options](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-federation-plugin/#options)?

I saw tutorials suggesting the use of a few different keys (below `name`, `filename` and `exposes`) but I can't find those options in the [official plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-federation-plugin/#options) documentation.

There is also, kind of hidden, general information on [module federation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/) where I am able to guess what `name` does, but nothing on `filename`.

```js
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: "myModule",
  filename: "remoteEntry/js",
  exposes: {
    ModuleApp: "./src/bootstrap",
  },
})
```

The closest I got is when looking at the type definitions (below). But it is quite difficult to understand without comments.

```js
new ContainerPlugin({
    name: options.name,
    library,
    filename: options.filename,
    runtime: options.runtime,
    shareScope: options.shareScope,
    exposes: options.exposes
})
```

Any suggestions on how I am supposed to understand and use the API is very welcome.

Comment: The plugin's schema has good info (agree that this should be surfaced in the docs). https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/schemas/plugins/container/ModuleFederationPlugin.json#L479